# replace kosher pickle brine after leak

Tags: pickling

I made kosher dills for a Christmas gift and they turned out great. The jar tipped in transit and leaked all the brine. Can I refill it? With what?

Comment: Are they refrugerator pickles or properly canned?

Comment: I don't think they're either. As far as I understand refrigerator and/or canned pickles that is the process of boiling them and using vinegar. These are kosher dills which were made by allowing them to sit in a salt brine for over a week. The lactic fermentation made them sour and delicious. Since it's not vinegar, but fermented, I worry that there's no replacement liquid I can put them in.

Answer (score 1):

For fermented pickles, I suggest using a salty brine similar to the one you started with.

If you are really lucky, enough lactobacillae are present to recreate a pickling brine, otherwise a 5% salt solution should help keeping the cucumbers for a bit longer.

Instruct the recipients to use the pickles rather quickly, I'd *guestimate* a week in the refrigerator should be ok.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the suggestion! Might also suggest we just eat them immediately.